# Imprimir 5 vezes o numero 5 na tela

Tags: javascript

Estou praticando um exercício de javascript que pede que usemos a função "for" para repetir 5 vezes o número 5 na tela. Mas alegam que o código dá erro e não sei o que estou fazendo de errado:

```js
function imprimir5vezes(){
  
  for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
console.log(i)
  } 
}
```

Em tempo, para checar, o que devo escrever no console para checar a função é console.log(i) ou console.log(imprimir5vezes)?

Obrigada!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?
Então do jeito que você colocou você vai estar imprimindo a variavel i ,logo ela não sera o numero 5 nas 5 impressões, mas vai assumir cada vez um valor, do 0 até o 4.
O correto nesse caso seria

```js
 function imprimir5vezes(){

  for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
     console.log(5)
  } 
}
```

Comment: Oi Luan! Muitissimo obrigada!

Comment: Não foi nada, e mais uma coisa quando postar duvidas sobre exercicios caso esteja fazendo em alguma plataforma tente especificar ela, assim caso alguem ja saiba do que se trata ou tenha passado pela mesma coisa vai ser mais facil responderem.

Answer (score 1):

Jsjsj, então, colega você está imprimindo o iterador do laço, ou seja, a cada ciclo ele está incrementando, na verdade a sua função estão dando algo parecido com isso :

```
//0,1,2,3,4
```

O correto, para imprimir 5 vezes o número 5 seria assim :

```
function função() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) { 
        console.log( 5 );
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado, boa sorte com tuas linhas de códigos ☺️

Comment: Muito obrigada Miqueias!!

Comment: Dnd, somente uma dúvida, é do Santander coders?

Answer (score 0):

No seu código você está exibindo o valor da variável `i` cinco vezes no `console`, o que vai te dar uma sequência de:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

**Exemplo**

```js
function imprimir5vezes(){
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
        console.log(i)
    } 
}

imprimir5vezes();
```

Isso porque se o valor de `i` for menor que `5` vai ser exibido no `console` o valor de `i` que é `0` e depois vai incrementar `1` e depois volta e faz o mesmo procedimento até chegar um ponto que `5` não vai ser menor que `5`, assim o loop para de ser executado. Para o que você deseja, é só colocar um `Number` ou uma `String` representando o valor `5` no `console`.

**Exemplo**

```js
function imprimir5vezes(){
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
        console.log(5)
    } 
}

imprimir5vezes();
```

Assim o resultado vai ser parecido com o seu código, o que muda é que cada iteração do loop `for` não vai ser exibido o valor de `i` e sim um valor `5`.